# How do elements of a Union define eachother?

Tags: c, unions

I was looking at a tutorial on unions in c. At the end of the tutorial there was an exercise regarding unions. I do not understand how the solution code works.

Exercise:

Create a union that stores an array of 21 characters and 6 ints (6 since
21  / 4 == 5, but 5 * 4 == 20 so you need 1 more for the purpose of this
exercise),  you  will  set the integers to 6 given values and then print
out the character array both as a series of chars and as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union hiddenMessage {
    int  ints[6];
    char chars[21];
};

int main() {
    union hiddenMessage intCharacters = {{1853169737, 1936876900, 1684955508, 1768838432, 561213039, 0}};

    printf("[");
    // only go to 18 because 1 byte is for the terminating 0 and we don't print the last in the loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; ++i)
        printf("%c, ", intCharacters.chars[i]);
    printf("%c]\n", intCharacters.chars[19]);
    printf("%s\n", intCharacters.chars);
}
```

The output:

```
[I,  , u, n, d, e, r, s, t, a, n, d,  , U, n, i, o, n, s, !]
I understand Unions!
```

It seems the values of intCharacters.ints defines the values of intCharacters.chars. Could someone elaborate on how this work?

Comment: All members of a union share memory. If you write to one member of a union, all members are modified. I recommend you rewrite those integer values in hexadecimal format, and you should start seeing the ASCII values of the characters in there.

Comment: Note: to *really* understand unions (and integers), you should think about why it's possible that the same program running on different hardware or OS might instead print `[n, u,  , I, s, r, e, d, d, n, a, t, i, n, U, !, s, n, o] nu IsreddnatinU!sno`.  Among other things.

Answer (score 3):

The members of a union occupy the *same* memory.  A visualization may help:

```
Address       chars       Bytes      ints
-------       -----       -----      ----          
                       +----------+ ---+---
0x4000        chars[0] | 'I' 0x49 |    |
                       +----------+    |
0x4001        chars[1] | ' ' 0x20 |    |
                       +----------+  ints[0]
0x4002        chars[2] | 'U' 0x55 |    |
                       +----------+    |
0x4003        chars[3] | 'n' 0x6E |    |
                       +----------+ ---+---
0x4004        chars[4] | 'd' 0x64 |    |
                       +----------+    |
0x4005        chars[5] | 'e' 0x65 |    |
                       +----------+  ints[1]
0x4006        chars[6] | 'r' 0x72 |    |
                       +----------+    |
0x4007        chars[7] | 's' 0x73 |    |
                       +----------+ ---+---
                           ...
```

This should be enough to get the point across.

The array elements `chars[0]` through `char[3]` occupy the same bytes as `ints[0]`, `chars[4]` through `chars[7]` occupy the same bytes as `ints[1]`, etc.

The initial value of `ints[0]` is `1853169737`.  The hexadecimal representation of this value is `0x6E752049`.  On a little-endian system like x86, the individual bytes of that integer value are ordered as `0x49`, `0x20`, `0x75`, `0x6E`.  `0x49` is the ASCII code for the character `'I'`, `0x20` is the ASCII code for the character `' '`, etc.

Hence, the integer value `1853169737` has the same bit pattern as the sequence of characters `'I'`, `' '`, `'U'`, `'n'`, `1936876900` has the same bit pattern as `'d'`, `'e'`, `'r'`, `'s'`, etc.

Be aware that this example makes 3 critical assumptions about the underlying platform - that an `int` is 4 bytes wide, that multi-byte types use little-endian ordering, meaning bytes are ordered from least significant to most significant, and that the underlying character set is ASCII (or UTF-8).  None of those cases have to be true everywhere.  Using unions in this manner can expose you to platform-specific weirdness and such code tends to not be portable.  If you're not concerned with portability that's not a problem, but if you want to write code that can run on a wide variety of hardware or operating systems, you have to be aware of such things.

Comment: Another assumption of the program that does not hold everywhere is that the runtime character set is congruent with ASCII.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yup, that too.  I'll update.

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you, makes sense. Coming from a beginner, jumping from Python to C reveals how much more there is to programming. For example stuff like this never came across in my projects in Python.